Is there a way to distribute a customtkinter app and issue updates?
I am creating a GUI desktop app in Python (3.10) using customtkinter. I would like to be able to distribute the app to Windows and macOS. The tricky part is that I also want the ability to roll out updates. My target audience for this is not tech-savvy, so i would like to make the install and update process easy. Is there a tool out there for something like this?
Using pyinstaller, the .exe is flagged as malware, and I don't think i could update the code anyway. I've also tried using Nuitka to make an exe, but I don't believe there is a way to do updates that way. BeeWare seems like a good option, but getting it to work with tkinter requires some workarounds that I don't understand.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I’m not exactly sure for the malware, but maybe this post could help.
As for the updates, you could create a simple update script, update.py (then convert to .exe. This script would get the data from the web (yourdomain.com/app.exe), and download it to C:\program files (or whatever for the os)
A simple windows example would look like this:

import requests


file_url = 'https://yourdomain.com/app.exe'

response = requests.get(file_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('C:\Program Files\app\app.exe', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)


Then invoke that from your app every time an “update” button is pressed.
